# Manipulating Multiline section in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I am looking to extract and then prepend to a list of items within a section from a text file. Sed and grep almost work, but they need a lot of hacking. Is there another utility that makes this easier, perhaps awk?

First, the extraction. I want a list of all the items between "section [" and "]", but there might be whitespace/newlines inside that first pattern which makes look-behinds difficult. The newlines make a nice list deliminator, so I just want ALL the characters between "[" and "]" of the specific section (i.e. 'section [ ]' and not 'wrongSection [ ]')

Examples of the text (there will only be 1 section per file):

File 1:

```
section []
wrongSection [foo]
```

Output 1 Empty

File 2:

```
section [item1]
wrongSection [foo]
```

Output 2:

```
item1
```

File 3:

```
section
[
    item1
    item2
]
wrongSection [foo]
```

Output 3:

```
item1
item2
```

Grep can be used to grab it, but it won't ignore the non-capture groups

```
$ grep -Po "(?ims)^(?:\s*section\s*\n*\s*\[).*?(?:\])" file.txt
```

My second problem is prepending a new item ('itemX').
Sed hates multilines, but the following works if I assume the [ is within 1 line

```
$ sed '/^\s*section/N;/^\s*section\s*\n?\s*\[/a itemX' file.txt
```

In summary, I am trying to read/prepend multiple lines between a possible-multiline pattern I don't want in the output. Am I better off scrapping bash and using perl/groovy/python/etc.?

Comment: What is your expected output from above text file?

Comment: The first one: "". The second: "item1". The third: "item1\nitem2". Edited my post to add this

Comment: The standard UNIX tool for manipulating text in general is awk so just use that. At this point, it's become very unclear, to me at least, what it is you're trying to do. Maybe clean up your question to simply show some sample input and the final expected output?

Comment: My apologies, I've added 3 example input/outputs

Comment: Are you keying off the specific word "section" or do you just want the first text that's between "[" and "]" in your file?

Comment: The specific word 'section'. I admit, I chose poorly in my wording

Comment: So, if you had an input file with "bob [ foo ]" before "section [ bar ]" you'd expect to see "bar" output, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it'll work with any modern awk:

```
$ cat file1
section []
wrongSection [foo]
$ 
$ awk -v RS=']' 'sub(/.*section[[:space:]]+\[*/,""){gsub(/^\n+|\n+$/,""); gsub(/[[:blank:]]/,""); print; exit}' file1


$ cat file2                                                                   
section [item1]
wrongSection [foo]
$ 
$ awk -v RS=']' 'sub(/.*section[[:space:]]+\[*/,""){gsub(/^\n+|\n+$/,""); gsub(/[[:blank:]]/,""); print; exit}' file2
item1

$ cat file3                                                                   
section
[
    item1
    item2
]
wrongSection [foo]
$ 
$ awk -v RS=']' 'sub(/.*section[[:space:]]+\[*/,""){gsub(/^\n+|\n+$/,""); gsub(/[[:blank:]]/,""); print; exit}' file3
item1
item2
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Using non-gnu awk:

```
awk -v FS='[ \n]*[\\[\\]][ \n]*' '{gsub(/\n+ +/, "\n");
           for(i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) {if ($i=="section") print $(i+1)}}' RS= file

\n
item1\n
item1\n
item2\n
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost works, but it reads the items in other sections as well. I added an edit to show what a file looks like. Your solution returns 'itemY' and 'itemX' when I only want 'itemY'. Is there a way to exit the awk script when it encounters the first ']'?